Box2d into opengl/opengl es?
I recently learned a little bit of OpenGL through learnopengl.com. I've got through the window, gone through the triangle, then shaders along with interpolation, textures, and now transform. When I say transform, meaning I can move the shape I created a shape I made to anywhere on the screen, and now I wish to implement physics. I'll be using Box2D since it's popular, and I like to know how to get it working. Going through the demos found in the samples, I can't seem to figure out how the shapes in opengl are given position to the b2body. Does anyone have any idea on how I can go about this?
Code:
#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <stb_image.h>

#include <box2d/box2d.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>

#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <shader_s.h>

#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{

    // Define the gravity vector.
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);

    // Construct a world object, which will hold and simulate the rigid bodies.
    b2World world(gravity);

    // Define the ground body.
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);

    // Call the body factory which allocates memory for the ground body
    // from a pool and creates the ground box shape (also from a pool).
    // The body is also added to the world.
    b2Body* groundBody = world.CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);

    // Define the ground box shape.
    b2PolygonShape groundBox;

    // The extents are the half-widths of the box.
    groundBox.SetAsBox(50.0f, 10.0f);

    // Add the ground fixture to the ground body.
    groundBody->CreateFixture(&groundBox, 0.0f);

    // Define the dynamic body. We set its position and call the body factory.
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, 4.0f);
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Define another box shape for our dynamic body.
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;

    // Set the box density to be non-zero, so it will be dynamic.
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;

    // Override the default friction.
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;

    // Add the shape to the body.
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    // Prepare for simulation. Typically we use a time step of 1/60 of a
    // second (60Hz) and 10 iterations. This provides a high quality simulation
    // in most game scenarios.
    float timeStep = 1.0f / 60.0f;
    int32 velocityIterations = 6;
    int32 positionIterations = 2;
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // build and compile our shader zprogram
    // ------------------------------------
    Shader ourShader("4.1.texture.vs", "4.1.texture.fs");

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
    };
    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 3, // first triangle
        1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };
    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    // load and create a texture 
    // -------------------------
    unsigned int texture1, texture2;
    // texture 1
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    int width, height, nrChannels;
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true); // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis.
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(("resources/textures/container.jpg"), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);
    // texture 2
    // ---------
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    // load image, create texture and generate mipmaps
    data = stbi_load(("resources/textures/awesomeface.png"), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        // note that the awesomeface.png has transparency and thus an alpha channel, so make sure to tell OpenGL the data type is of GL_RGBA
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to load texture" << std::endl;
    }
    stbi_image_free(data);

    // tell opengl for each sampler to which texture unit it belongs to (only has to be done once)
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ourShader.use();
    ourShader.setInt("texture1", 0);
    ourShader.setInt("texture2", 1);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // bind textures on corresponding texture units
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        // create transformations
        glm::mat4 transform = glm::mat4(1.0f); // make sure to initialize matrix to identity matrix first
        transform = glm::translate(transform, glm::vec3(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f));
        transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        // get matrix's uniform location and set matrix
        ourShader.use();
        unsigned int transformLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.ID, "transform");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(transformLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(transform));

        // render container
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // optional: de-allocate all resources once they've outlived their purpose:
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

   



    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}




void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}






void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}


I'm not quite sure what you mean by "given position to". You'll have a collection of fixtures/physics bodies with positions, and a collection of mesh instances to render with positions, and code you write will copy the positions from the physics bodies to the mesh instances. Can you show us how you've tried writing that code so far, and where you got stuck or need help?

Yeah sorry about that. I'm new to posting my code on here and don't really know what I'm doing
